Whom can we worship always even in the bathroom?
I heard that Lord Shiva name can be chanted in any situation even while in sex or in bathroom doing number 2 work or even before bath.
Because there should be some god to protect us during these situations also right? What if something life threatening happens and somebody cannot stop praying to god saying its not the right time.

Draupadi was menstruating when she prayed to Lord Krishna during the vastraharan incident. So the name of Lord Krishna/Vishnu can be taken in any situation. Regarding Lord Shiva, learned members can clarify.

Bhagavān smaraṇa (and mānasa japa of Bhagavān nāma such as 'Rāma') can be done anywhere in any situation (as in, there's no śāstrīya restriction regarding that). But pūjā, vācika & upāṁśu japa (of mantras), etc., cannot be done anywhere and in any situation though. For e.g., if a woman is on periods, she cannot do pūjā or pūjā related kriyās (such as cooking prasāda), but she can do Bhagavān smaraṇa.
